# Как в state React измени объекти вложенные в массив при динамическом рендере дополнительных полей

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

Ребята, всем привет!
Нужна помощь знатоков React, самому не получается решить, похожих ситуаций не нашел ни здесь ни на бругих форумах ((((
У меня есть React сомпонент в state которого есть массив с объектами (phones), именно такую форму нужно отправлять на сервер, (handleChangeTel) метод класса который должен записывать данные в стейт, но вот с ним и проблема, не получается правильно сделать запись так как количество номеров телефона может увеличиваться динамически , метод класса createItem динамически увеличивает количество номеров.
В return первый это два инпута которые есть стабильно а дальше ([...Array(createItemIdx)]), инпуты которие рендерятся по нажатию на кнопку (IconButton) и их может бить сколько угодно.

Помогите кто знает как решить забачку, я уже 4 день мучаюсь, код могу кинуть в текстовом формате.

````
  state = {
    phones: [{ title: "", number: "" }],
    createItemIdx: 0,
    ...this.props.contact,
  };

  handleChangeTel = (event, index) => {
    const { name, value } = event.currentTarget;
    console.log(index);
    console.log(this.state.phones);
    console.log(event.currentTarget);

    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      phones: [{ ...prevState.phones[index], [name]: value }],
    }));
  };

  createItem = () => {
    this.setState(({ createItemIdx }) => ({
      createItemIdx: createItemIdx + 1,
    }));
  };

  render() {
    const { phones, createItemIdx } = this.state;

    return (
      <form className={style.form_contact} onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          <div>Телефон</div>
          <input
            className={style.input_contact}
            type="text"
            name="title"
            value={phones[0].title}
            // value={title}
            onChange={(event) => {
              this.handleChangeTel(event, 0);
            }}
            placeholder="Мобільний, Домашній ..."
            required
          />
          <input
            className={style.input_contact}
            type="number"
            name="number"
            value={phones[0].number}
            // value={number}
            onChange={(event) => {
              this.handleChangeTel(event, 0);
            }}
            required
          />
        </label>

        {[...Array(createItemIdx)].map(() => (
          <label>
            <div>Телефон </div>
            <input
              className={style.input_contact}
              type="text"
              name="title"
              // value={phones[1].title}
              onChange={(event) => {
                this.handleChangeTel(event, 1);
              }}
              placeholder="Мобільний, Домашній ..."
              // required
            />
            <input
              className={style.input_contact}
              type="number"
              name="number"
              // value={phones[1].number}
              onChange={(event) => {
                this.handleChangeTel(event, 1);
              }}
              // required
            />
          </label>
        ))}

        <div>
          <IconButton onClick={this.createItem}>
            <Add width="10" height="10" />
          </IconButton>
        </div>

        <button type="submit">
          {this.state.id ? "Редагувати" : "Зберегти"}
        </button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
export default ContactForm;```
````

Answer (score 0):

Вот так можно отрендерить данные из массива

```
render() {
const { phones, createItemIdx } = this.state;

return (
    <form className={style.form_contact} onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        {phones.map((phone, index) => {
            return <label key={index}>
                <div>Телефон</div>
                <input
                    className={style.input_contact}
                    type="text"
                    name="title"
                    value={phone.title}
                    onChange={(event) => {
                        this.handleChangeTel(event, 0);
                    }}
                    placeholder="Мобільний, Домашній ..."
                    required
                />
                <input
                    className={style.input_contact}
                    type="number"
                    name="number"
                    value={phone.number}
                    onChange={(event) => {
                        this.handleChangeTel(event, 0);
                    }}
                    required
                />
            </label>
        })}
        <div>
            <IconButton onClick={this.createItem}>
                <Add width="10" height="10" />
            </IconButton>
        </div>

        <button type="submit">
            {this.state.id ? "Редагувати" : "Зберегти"}
        </button>
    </form>
);
}
```